# Check for a cookie with Python Flask

Tags: python, session, cookies, flask

I would like to get a cookie (e.g. `country`) with this Flask call.

```
data = request.cookies.get("country")
```

How can I tell if the cookie exists?

Comment: And what did you try? Did `request.cookies.get()` not work?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`request.cookies` is a `dict`, so:

```
from flask import request

if 'country' in request.cookies:
    # do something
else:
    # do something else
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As a quick basic follow up (im new to this), would this work: if 'country' not in request.cookies: #do something

Comment: @user1738522 umm, well, I can just load a Python interpreter, type, `d = {}`, then `if 'something' not in d: print 'not there'` and get 'not there' - so errr... ?

Comment: @Jimmy yes, that is a valid piece of code and would work!

Answer (score 7):

```
request.cookies.get('my_cookie')
```

should have worked. If it didn't work, you may not have access to the request object when you call this line.

Try importing flask at the top

```
import flask
```

then call

```
cookie = flask.request.cookies.get('my_cookie')
```

If the cookies exists, it will get assigned to `cookie` and if not then `cookie` will equal `None`

Comment: Seems like this actually returns a 400 Bad Request because the cookie is not provided.