# Flask - unable to get cookies

Tags: python, flask, cookies, jwt

I have the following endpoint starting an Authorization flow:

```
@spotify_auth_bp.route("/index", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def spotify_index():
    CODE = "code"
    CLIENT_ID =   os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID')
    SCOPE = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_SCOPE')
    REDIRECT_URI = os.environ.get('SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI')

    SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL = "https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize"

    return redirect("{}?response_type={}&client_id={}&scope={}&redirect_uri={}".format(
        SPOTIFY_AUTH_URL, CODE, CLIENT_ID, SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI), code=302)
```

Then I get redirect back from Spotify to `/callback`, where I am setting `jwt` cookies in my response, like so:

```
 @spotify_auth_bp.route("/callback", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def spotify_callback():
    token = user.encode_access_token(access_token)
    a11n_h, a11n_d, a11n_s = token.decode().split('.')
    response = make_response(redirect('http://localhost/about', code=302))
    response.set_cookie('a11n.h', a11n_h)
    response.set_cookie('a11n.d', a11n_d) 
    response.set_cookie('a11n.s', a11n_s, httponly=True)  

    return response
```

And cookies show up in my browser console, under 'Application'.

---

Now I would like to get them from another endpoint, like so:

```
@spotify_auth_bp.route("/get_token/<user_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_token(user_id):
    # get access token cookies
    a11n_h = request.cookies.get('a11n.h')
    a11n_d = request.cookies.get('a11n.d')
    a11n_s = request.cookies.get('a11n.s')
```

But I'm printing these cookies as `None`, `None`, `None`

also, I have NO `Flask` config...

```
app.config.update(
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True,
    SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE='Lax',
)
```

...which could prevent cookies from being sent over `http`.

---

What am I missing?

---

OBS: I'm testing this endpoint using `Postman`, and in Headers I've set the key `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to the value `true`.

Comment: First of all, as described in the flask doc: Secure "If True, the cookie will only be available via HTTPS." Are you using https ? If you do not, then flask do not send cookies. That's why it's None. After that if the cookie are in the web browser but are not sent back. May be you have set the config: SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE=True or some other headers that prevent cookie to be sent over http. Take a look at https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/security/

Comment: @Victor thanks for your comment. I've edited my question. I'n not using https, and I don't have config that prevents cookies being sent over http...any ideas?

Comment: Not really, I mean if the cookies show up in the browser it's seems that they are not sent back. You can use the Console (F12) of your web browser and check what is sent in the request when you click on /callback. And also use, use url_for in your redirect: redirect(url_for(<name_of_the_function_with_/about_decorator>))

Comment: @Victor there is no function for localhost, nor '/', nor any 'about' decorator. those urls are handled at frontend with React.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the above, i assume you are using a frontend application based on any other framework and using libraries like axios, fetch, request, etc to hit API on the flask.

So, you might have missed out that you need to set a flag in request to allow sending cookies. Refer to below links to find ways to do it:

1. Fetch API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included

```
    fetch('https://example.com', {
      credentials: 'include'
    });
```

2. XMLHttpRequest

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://example.com/', true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.send(null);
```

Correct me, if doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: visit this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39923306/10798048 it might solve the case

Comment: It solved the problem. I've posted an answer in order to detail how it was solved, but I've accepted and rewarded your answer. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

the following worked (as suggested in the answer from Dhruv Agarwal):

```
getToken(event) {
    const {userId} = this.props
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/get_token/1`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`,
      }
    };

    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true // <--------------------

    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('res.data.data)
    })    
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
```

I don't know what was missing in my Postman request, but now it's functional.